# How to break down large 'macro' classes?

Tags: c#, architecture

One application I work on does only one thing, looking from outside world. Takes a file as input and after ~5 minutes spits out another file.

What happens inside is actually a sequential series of action. The application is, in our opinion, structured well because each action is like a small box, without too many dependencies.

Usually some later actions use some information from previous one and just a few can be executed in parallel - for the sake of simplicity we prefer to the execution sequential.

Now the problem is that the function that executes all this actions is like a batch file: a long list of calls to different functions with different arguments. So, looking in the code it looks like:

```
main
{
    try
    {
        result1 = Action1(inputFile);
        result2 = Action2(inputFile);
        result3 = Action3(result2.value);
        result4 = Action4(result1.value, inputFile);
        ... //You get the idea. There is no pattern passed paramteres
        resultN = ActionN(parameters);
        write output
    }
    catch
    {
        something went wrong, display the error
    }
}
```

How would you model the main function of this application so is not just a long list of commands?

Answer (score 2):

Not everything needs to fit to a clever pattern.  There are few more elegant ways to express a long series of imperative statements than as, well, a long series of imperative statements.

If there are certain kinds of flexibility you feel you are currently lacking, express them, and we can try to propose solutions.

If there are certain clusters of actions and results that are re-used often, you could pull them out into new functions and build "aggregate" actions from them.

You could look in to dataflow languages and libraries, but I expect the gain to be small.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best approach, but you could have an object that would store all the results and you would give it to each method in turn. Every method would read the parameters it needs and write its result there. You could then have a collection of actions (either as delegates or objects implementing an interface) and call them in a loop.

```
class Results
{
  public int Result1 { get; set; }
  public string Result2 { get; set; }
  …
}


var actions = new Action<Results>[] { Action1, Action2, … };

Results results = new Results();

foreach (var action in actions)
  action(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of implementing a Sequential Workflow from Windows Workflow

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this solution is far not bad. If the actions are disjunct, I mean there are no global parameters or other hidden dependencies between different actions or between actions and the environment, it's a good solution. Easy to maintain or read, and when you need to expand the functionality, you have just to add new actions, when the "quantity" changes, you have just to add or remove lines from the macro sequence. If there's no need for change frequently the process chain: **don't move**!

If it's a system, where the implementation of actions don't often changes, but their order and parameters yes, you may design a simple script language, and transform the macro class into that script. This script should be maintained by someone else than you, someone who is familiar with the problem domain in the level of your "actions". So, he/she can assembly the application using script language without your assistance.

One nice approach for that kind of problem splitting is **dataflow programming** (a.k.a. Flow-based programming). In dataflow programming, there are pre-written *components*. Components are black boxes (from the view of the application developer), they have consumer (input) and producer (output) ports, which can be connected to form a processing network, which is then the application. If there're a good set of components for a domain, many applications can created without programming new components. Also, components can be built of other components (they called composite components).

Wikipedia (good starting point):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming

JPM's site (book, wiki, everything):
http://jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/

I think, bigger systems must have that split point you describe as "macro". Even games have that point, e.g. FPS games have a 3D engine and a game logic script, or there's SCUMM VM, which is the same.